# Should aop and aspect-oriented tags be synonyms? Should they be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Should aop and aspect-oriented tags be synonyms? Should they be merged? I think so. I would like to hear your opinion.

I am referring to:

[aspect-oriented tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented)

and

[aop tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merge complete. Aspect-oriented is now the preferred tag, since it provides more meaning by itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas!